# Changing cells in a 4D numpy matrix subject to conditions on axis indexes

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have a 4D numpy array `A` with indexes `i, j, k, l` for the four dimensions, suppose `50 x 40 x 30 x 20`. Also suppose I have some other list `B`.

How can I set all cells in `A` that satisfy some condition to `0`? Is there a way to do it efficiently without loops (with vectorization?).

Example condition: All cells that have 3rd dimensional index `k` whereby `B[k] == x`

For instance,

if we have the 2D matrix `A = [[1,2],[3,4]]` and `B = [7,8]`

Then for the 2nd dimension of `A` (i.e. columns), I want to zero out all cells in the 2nd dimension whereby the index of the cell in that dimension (call the index `i`), satisfies the condition `B[i] == 7`. In this case, A will be converted to
`A = [[0,0],[3,4]]`.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want, could you give as a simple 2D example.

Comment: Done! added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify boolean arrays for specific axes:

```py
import numpy as np

i, j, k, l = 50, 40, 30, 20
a = np.random.random((i, j, k, l))
b_k = np.random.random(k)
b_j = np.random.random(j)

# i, j,         k, l
a[:, :, b_k < 0.5, :] = 0

# You can alsow combine multiple conditions along the different axes
# i,         j,         k, l
a[:, b_j > 0.5, b_k < 0.5, :] = 0

# Or work with the index explicitly
condition_k = np.arange(k) % 3 == 0  # Is the index divisible by 3?
# i, j,            k, l
a[:, :,  condition_k, :] = 0
```

To work with the example you have given

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]])
b = np.array([7, 8])

#      i, j
a[b == 7, :] = 0
# array([[0, 0],
#        [3, 4]])
```

Comment: This is checking some other array against a condition -- is there one that makes use of the axis in the 3rd dimension of matrix a instead?

Comment: I made a 3rd example, is this what you want?

Comment: please note that the first example I provided was basically the same as the last just another condition `b < x` instead `b == x`

Answer (score 1):

Does the following help?

```
A = np.arange(16,dtype='float64').reshape(2,2,2,2)
A[A == 2] = 3.14
```

I'm replacing the entry equal to 2 with 3.14. You can set it to some other value.

Comment: Er this is editing a particular (known) cell, rather than editing all cells that satisfy some condition

Comment: The ```A == 2``` inside the square brackets is a condition.  You can replace it with some other condition. For example, to replace all even entries you can do:

```A[A %2 == 0] = 3.14```

Comment: I see, is there a way such that can use the index of the entry as part of the condition? Rather than only the entry value?